# Passing a path directory to a function in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, pathname

I am new to PS and I am trying to write a function which takes in parameters from a global variable. I want to pass a path name read from a .txt file into a function in the same script.

```powershell
function GetCorrectChildren ([string] $homepath,$min,$max,$row)
{
    #Testpoint 2
    write-host "homepath = $homepath"
    $ColItem = (Get-ChildItem $homepath |? {$_.PSIsContainer} | sort-object)
}

foreach ($homepath in (Get-Content $PSScriptRoot\homepath_short.txt))
{
    $freeSpace = [win32api]::GetDiskFreeSpace("$homepath").FreeBytesAvailable / 1073741824
    $totalSpace = [win32api]::GetDiskFreeSpace("$homepath").TotalNumberOfBytes / 1073741824 
    $percentageFreeSpace = $freeSpace / $totalSpace * 100

    if($freeSpace -lt $threshold)
    {
    #Testpoint 1
    write-host "homepath = $homepath"
    GetCorrectChildren ("$homepath",$min,$max,$OriRow)
}
```

For `#Testpoint 1`, it returns the path name correctly which is `\\C:\test1\test_a`. However in `#Testpoint 2` it returns `\\C:\test1\test_a 20 30 System.Object`.
I don't understand what does the `20 30 System.Object` mean and where does it come from? Can some one shine some light on this? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Change the last line

```
GetCorrectChildren ("$homepath",$min,$max,$OriRow)
```

to

```
GetCorrectChildren $homepath $min $max $OriRow
```

as `("$homepath",$min,$max,$OriRow)` creates a single array with the four values and passes it to the function `GetCorrectChildren` as its first parameter so that `write-host "homepath = $homepath"` in it will print all 4 values